# Dynamic Control sets on combobox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I have several instances where a user may need to enter additional data based on a combobox selection. The number of necessary text boxes changes depending on selection (min 1- max 3). In order to keep these items organized, I have them in GroupBox(s). What I need is advice on achieving this effect. Should I programmatically add rows to a grid within the groupbox? Should I create all text boxes and labels and change visibility property on selection changed event? I do not really like the second idea because the groupbox will be scaled inappropriately if only one text field is required. I realize the general context of my question, as a novice with WPF I just need some advice on best practices to achieve this.

**Update**
I have tried to collapse the row on selection change. This gets rid of the content but will still leave my groupbox the same size.

```
 <GroupBox Name="gbCondensor" Height="Auto"  Header="Condensor"  
 FontSize="16" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
 Margin="20,0,20,92" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid Name="grdCondensor" Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="lblCondensorTemp" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
 Content="Condensor Temperature" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
 VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Width="255"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cmbCondensorTemp" FontSize= "16" Width="200" 
 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0" Height="30">
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Constant</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Linear</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Switching</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label Name="lblCondensorTempText" Content="Temperature" 
 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" 
 Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtCondensorTemp" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
Width="73"></TextBox>
            <Label Name="lblEndCondTemp" Content="Temperature" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.Row="3" ></Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtEndCondTemp" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" 
Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Width="73"></TextBox>
            <Label Name="lblSwitchCondTemp" Content="Temperature" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.Row="4" ></Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtSwitchCondTemp" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" 
Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Width="73"></TextBox>                
</GroupBox>
```

With this to collapse Rows in code:

```
     void CheckCondensorComboBox(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (cmbCondensorTemp.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            lblEndCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            txtEndCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            grdCondensor.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(0);
            lblSwitchCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            txtSwitchCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            grdCondensor.RowDefinitions[4].Height = new GridLength(0);
        }
        else if (cmbCondensorTemp.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {

            lblEndCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtEndCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            grdCondensor.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(30);
            lblSwitchCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            txtSwitchCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            grdCondensor.RowDefinitions[4].Height = new GridLength(0);
        }
        else if (cmbCondensorTemp.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            lblEndCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtEndCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            grdCondensor.RowDefinitions[3].Height = new GridLength(30);
            lblSwitchCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtSwitchCondTemp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            grdCondensor.RowDefinitions[4].Height = new GridLength(30);
        }

    }
```

What I am going for here is a group box that changes it's height based on the controls needed per user selection.

Comment: With regards to your second point, you shouldn't have problems with the size of the groupbox if the visibility is set to collapsed rather than hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your ideas are valid. The question is a little hard to answer specifically without seeing the code, but generally speaking I like to start by thinking about maintainability first - code is typically read many more times than it is written.

I suspect that simply collapsing the extra fields that aren't needed may be more straightforward and maintainable than creating extra fields and binding them at run time.

Try one way and see how it looks - don't spend too long weighing it up.

Comment: I have tried to collapse the row on selection change. This gets rid of the content but will still leave my groupbox the same size.

Comment: I have added some test code to post. This works for hiding content but not resizing groupbox.

Comment: @willkk - check that the grid rows which contain the GroupBox are not set to a fixed height.